# How to put string in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making this function, but I do not know how to route the data to a textbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Percent of Letters</title>
<textbox id = "a"></textbox>
<script>
    document.getElementById("a").value += "A:" aPercent "%";
    var str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";
    var a = (str.split('a').length);
    var b = (str.split('b').length);
    var c = (str.split('c').length);
    var d = (str.split('d').length);
    var e = (str.split('e').length);
    var f = (str.split('f').length);
    var g = (str.split('g').length);
    var h = (str.split('h').length);
    var i = (str.split('i').length);
    var j = (str.split('j').length);
    var k = (str.split('k').length);
    var l = (str.split('l').length);
    var m = (str.split('m').length);
    var n = (str.split('n').length);
    var o = (str.split('o').length);
    var p = (str.split('p').length);
    var q = (str.split('q').length);
    var r = (str.split('r').length);
    var s = (str.split('s').length);
    var t = (str.split('t').length);
    var u = (str.split('u').length);
    var v = (str.split('v').length);
    var x = (str.split('x').length);
    var y = (str.split('y').length);
    var z = (str.split('z').length); 
    var aPercent = (a / str.length * 100);
    var bPercent = (b / str.length * 100);
    var cPercent = (c / str.length * 100);
    var dPercent = (d / str.length * 100);
    var ePercent = (e / str.length * 100);
    var fPercent = (f / str.length * 100);
    var gPercent = (g / str.length * 100);
    var hPercent = (h / str.length * 100);
    var iPercent = (i / str.length * 100);
    var jPercent = (j / str.length * 100);
    var kPercent = (k / str.length * 100);
    var lPercent = (l / str.length * 100);
    var mPercent = (m / str.length * 100);
    var nPercent = (n / str.length * 100);
    var oPercent = (o / str.length * 100);
    var pPercent = (p / str.length * 100);
    var qPercent = (q / str.length * 100);
    var rPercent = (r / str.length * 100);
    var sPercent = (s / str.length * 100);
    var tPercent = (t / str.length * 100);
    var uPercent = (u / str.length * 100);
    var vPercent = (v / str.length * 100);
    var xPercent = (x / str.length * 100);
    var yPercent = (y / str.length * 100);
    var zPercent = (z / str.length * 100);
</script>
```

I want it to read as *(letter): x% of string*.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking. Could you put the code inside the question itself and try to better explain?

Comment: Can you please give more details about your question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please spend a couple of minutes reading how to ask a good question. :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot couple of things. Use `+` operator to concatenate strings and numbers. Just change this line:

`document.getElementById("a").value += "A:" aPercent "%";`

to

`document.getElementById("a").value += "A:" + aPercent + "%";`

And push it to the bottom of your code, after you've calculated all the percentages.

Also, `textbox` is not a valid HTML element. Use `textarea` instead. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/em3T6k3zNeytgs9x7nHI?p=preview).

Also, I'm guessing you are new to javascript, there are better ways to implement such logics. You don't have to define as many variables. You can just go with `array`s when you learn about them.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry about my bad question asking. I will look at other questions to learn next time.

Comment: Ok, so I did said changes, and the format works, but now the percent is undefined.

Comment: @MaheshGowda Can you post a plunker?

Comment: Never mind, it turns out I put the command to display a percent in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method please first include any jquery min js

```
  var a=5;
 $('.yourinputBoxclassname').val(a);
  var a='your string';
 $('.yourinputBoxclassname').val(a);
```